# Widget freezes when add image background

Tags: ios, swiftui, widget

In my application, I have widgets with text, and they can have either an image or a gradient as the background.

- When a gradient is used as the background, the widgets work perfectly. They update when necessary and display everything correctly.
- When an image is used as the background, the widget freezes and looks like at the screenshot below. The images are up to 50 KB in size and I store them in the assets of the widget extension.
- If I only use an image or a gradient without any text, the widget works fine. But when both text and an image as the background are present, the widget doesn't display the text and freezes.

The Xcode preview and gallery preview on the device display everything correctly and up to date. However, when widget added to the home screen, it appears as shown in the screenshot below. What could be the issue?

Thanks!

My code:

```
import SwiftUI
import WidgetKit

struct HomeScreenWidgetView: View {
    let message: String
    let theme: AppTheme
    
    var body: some View {
        if !theme.imageName.isEmpty {
            Image("\(theme.imageName)")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
        }
        
        if !theme.widgetColors.isEmpty {
            LinearGradient(
                gradient: Gradient(colors: theme.widgetColors),
                startPoint: theme.startPoint,
                endPoint: theme.endPoint
            )
        }
        
        Text(message)
    }
}
```

Frozen widget:
[image: Frozen widget]

Comment: Instead of `Image("\(theme.imageName)")` have you tried `Image(theme.imageName)`? You don't need String interpolation for, what I presume is, a String.